# Entities relationships design to avoid recursion (Many-To-Many)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson, h2

I am building small app which is Estonian-English-Estonian dictionary. English and estonian words are represented as Entities (tables) in database. Each entity contains word/phrase on its language and List of translations which `List<Translation language>`. I have many-to-many relationships between them - what means that many english words have many estonian translations and many estonian words have many english translations. (which seems to me logical). I am facing the problem when I am fetching a word on either language and getting JSON representation - infinite loop occurs, which is expected because each entity contains list of opposite entities and those entities contain List of opposite entities and so on...
How would be possible to solve this problem? NOTE: I tried adding `@JsonIgnore` to either side - but when I fetch this side entity I have not resolved List of other entities and vice-versus. `@JsonManaged` and `@JsonBacked` do not solve the problem also. I need both sides entities to be resolved but without recursion.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "english_word")
public class EnglishWord {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "word")
   private String word;


   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinTable(name = "estonian_english",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "englishWord_id")
   ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "estonianWord_id"))
   private List<EstonianWord> translations = new ArrayList<>();

   public EnglishWord(String word) {
       this.word = word;
   }

   public EnglishWord() {
   }
-------------------------------------------------------------------

@Entity
@Table(name = "estonian_word")
public class EstonianWord {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "word")
   private String word;


   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinTable(name = "estonian_english",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "estonianWord_id")
           ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "englishWord_id"))
   private List<EnglishWord> translations = new ArrayList<>();

   public EstonianWord(String word) {
       this.word = word;
   }

   public EstonianWord() {
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use own DTO object to represent request/response.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this option. However, just is out of interest how to solve the current issue.

Comment: Okay, using DTO is good practice for problem like yours to create differents views for differents requests. But I found `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation, you can try with it. Btw `@JsonManagedReference` with `@JsonBackRererence` should works too. I now see a problem with the mana-to-many relationship itself as well. You should use `@JoinTable` only in one of the entities, in the second use only `mappedBy` in `@ManyToMany`. You can try [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-map-bidirectional-many-many-association/)

Comment: Actually I moved to DTO option and everything works as expected now. However, @JsonIdentityInfo might be the solution, I will read about it.